# how to know whether memory mapped file (boost::mapped_file_sink) has been flushed to the disk or not?

Tags: c++, boost, mmap

How to know that a mapped_file_sink has been flushed to the disk? There are not any function provided by boost for the same purpose.

I am writing to the mapped_file_sink and i need to move this file when it has been written to the disk.

Comment: Close the mapped file and move.

Comment: @sehe, boost memory map does not work this way. even if you close the mapped file it does not sync it to the disk on close. it just unmaps the memory map and then OS takes over to flush to the disk when it gets chance to do that. process needs to wait before doing anything with the file on disk.